# Python: how to set a time to trigger a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

How can I set a timer to run a function? right now I manually run the function. But what if I want to tell Python to run it in like 1 hour? how can I achieve this task?
Additionally, how about trying to run it at say 5pm today or tomorrow?

I tried the following but does not really work. What did I miss?

```
import datetime
from threading import timer
def hello_world():
    print("hello world")
delta_t = datetime.time(0,1,0)
Timer(delta_t, hello_world)
```

Comment: You probably can use `crontab` or `sleep 3600; python3 file.py`.

Comment: What is your operating system? If you don't want to leave a python process running (waiting until the desired time), you can use your operating system's task scheduler. In Unix-like operating systems that would be `crontab`.

Comment: I am using Window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import threading

def task():
    print("hello world ")

timer = threading.Timer(5.0, task)
timer.start()
```

Comment: thanks. it works. I guess 5.0 is the second. what if I want 2 hours but dont want to use it in seconds?

Comment: I haven't found any thing throw which you can pass hour of time format.